# How to select count of second degree BackrefAccessor in Peewee?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, peewee

I'm using the (excellent) Python Peewee ORM in my Flask app. I've got the following models (simplified):

```
class User(BaseModel):
    name = TextField(null=True)

class UserTransaction(BaseModel):
    user = ForeignKeyField(User, related_name='user_transactions')
    amount = DecimalField(default=0)

class UserCoTransaction(BaseModel):
    user_transaction = ForeignKeyField(UserTransaction, related_name='user_co_transactions')
```

I now have a user selected as follows:

```
user = User.select().where(User.id == 3).first()
```

And for this user I want to get all `user_transactions`, which have no `user_co_transaction`. I tried the following:

```
user.user_transactions.where(UserTransaction.user_co_transactions.count() == 0)
```

but that gives me a `AttributeError: 'BackrefAccessor' object has no attribute 'count'`.

Does anybody know how I can get for a user all `user_transactions` for which there are no `user_co_transactions`?

Answer (score 2):

I think this may do the trick:

```
(UserTransaction
 .select()
 .where(UserTransaction.user == user)
 .join(UserCoTransaction, JOIN.LEFT_OUTER)
 .group_by(UserTransaction)
 .having(fn.COUNT(UserCoTransaction.id) == 0))
```

Explanation:

You want to select from the user transaction table where the joined table has a count() of 0. So we select from the user transaction table, join (using left outer) on the cotransaction table, and filter the aggregate result to exclude those with count of cotxn != 0.

Comment: sad that this is what the backtrack leaves us with, but yes this is the official doc correct method for accessing complpex backtrack objects for now (2019) -- oof